# update multiple dropdown menus at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm still very new to rails so forgive me if this question just doesn't make any sense. However, I have a requirement to update several dropdown boxes in a report (which has one dropdown per row) at the same time. So, instead of clicking each dropdown in each row and selecting the status, what the user would like to do is press a button (or some other action) that changes all rows to a particular status. This functionality would be similar to selecting several checkboxes next to unread emails in gmail and hitting the "mark as read" button.

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: well what exactly is the problem how much have you done, what have you tried ?

Comment: currently i have a page with several rows and three editable fields. Two of which are drop downs. At this point, I'm still trying to get the whole page to save with a Save button but I'm unable to do that at the moment. So, i haven't tried anything yet w/r/t multiple selecting.

Comment: why doesn't it save ? Is it a nested attribute problem?

Comment: couldn't say. I have a feeling it's developer error ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help get you started:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple
http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes

Comment: thanks, i think this is the right direction. i could use some help here though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550203/autogenerate-paths-in-rails-3