# autogenerate paths in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

From the looks of some railscasts ([this one in particular](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple)), it seems like there is some autogeneration of "*_path" variables that not happening for me. in this rails cast, the edit_mutliple_products_path seems to be generated automagically (i don't normally like using that word). When I follow through the same steps and try to access a similar path, i get this:

```
undefined local variable or method `edit_multiple_distributions_workflows_path' for #<#<Class:0x132b18a68>:0x132af3290>
```

Comment: Does "rake routes" show your path in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rails 2.X. Rails routes changed in Rails 3. in order to get this route add below to routes.rb:

```
resources :products do
  collection do
    post 'edit_multiple'
    put  'update_multiple'
  end
end
```

You will be able to access this paths with

```
edit_multiple_products_url
edit_multiple_products_path
update_multiple_products_url
update_multiple_products_path
```

instead of `edit_multiple_distributions_workflow_path`. Btw where did you get this path from? I did not see it in the railscast.

Comment: yeah, "distributions_workflows" is from my own project. thanks for the help

Comment: also, could you briefly explain the difference between `*_url` and `*_path`?

Comment: Say you are www.amazon.com products_path returns /products while products_url returns www.amazon.com/products. Basically *_url returns the path prefixed with the host, and port if any, while *_path only returns the path.

Answer (score 1):

In the given tutorial, which looks like it's from an older Rails, this is the line which would generate the path methods:

```
map.resources :products, :collection => { :edit_multiple => :post, :update_multiple => :put }
```

In rails 3, you can see its usage in the docs here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: I could use something more high level about routing. But thanks for the direction. it's very helpful.